# Is there an alternative to using access keys to authenticate a mobile application to invoke an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, lambda, identity-management, access-keys

I built a mobile application using React Native and Expo Go. This application makes use of 1 serverless AWS Lambda function. Currently, this application invokes the Lambda function through the use of the AWS JavaScript SDK (`@aws-sdk/client-lambda`). In order to provide the `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`, I created a user with programmatic access in AWS IAM with an inline policy attatched, giving the permission to the user only to invoke the specific function that is needed.

As I am currently looking to deploy this application, I was wondering if it is okay for me to deploy this application using these access keys, or if there is a more secure way of authenticating the applicaiton in order for it to invoke the Lambda function.

Thanks!

My current setup is an IAM User with programmatic access (access keys) and an inline policy only allowing the user to invoke the Lambda function that is needed. This currently works, but I am worried this is not a good security practice and that I should instead authenticate the application with an alternative way.

Comment: Are your users all anonymous i.e. no login or will they login? The answer of what to use alternatively will differ based on this but regardless, it's not the best idea :)

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for your reply! My users have to login to the app. I am currently using firebase authentication to authenticate the users.